# 404 returned by gitlab API when trying to save terraform state to backend

Tags: gitlab, terraform

After having setup the gitlab backend using this [doc](https://awstip.com/provisioning-infrastructure-on-aws-with-gitlab-using-gitlab-managed-terraform-state-d06c13c9efd1), I use the `terraform apply` and expect the remote state to update accordingly. I get this 404 response from the gitlab API.

```
2022-11-28T20:50:47.082+0200 [DEBUG] POST https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<REDACTED PROJECT ID>/terraform/state/?ID=xxx-xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxx
╷
│ Error: Failed to save state
│
│ Error saving state: HTTP error: 404

│ Error: Failed to persist state to backend
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found three items of importance:

1. It is not necessary to generate a token! Username `'gitlab-ci-token'` and token `${CI_JOB_TOKEN}` work.
2. After I used predefined CI variables in the "address", the 404 error disappeared for me. Valid value: `'${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/example'`
3. It seems to be a good idea to use the gitlab terraform image for the agent

```
stages:
  - deploy
  - destroy

image: 
  name: "$CI_TEMPLATE_REGISTRY_HOST/gitlab-org/terraform-images/stable:latest"

variables:
    TF_PASSWORD: $CI_JOB_TOKEN
    TF_ADDRESS: '${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/example'
    TF_USERNAME: 'gitlab-ci-token'

tf_apply:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - source $(which gitlab-terraform)
    - >
       gitlab-terraform init \
        -backend-config=address=${TF_ADDRESS} \
        -backend-config=lock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
        -backend-config=unlock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
        -backend-config=username=${TF_USERNAME} \
        -backend-config=password=${TF_PASSWORD} \
        -backend-config=lock_method=POST \
        -backend-config=unlock_method=DELETE \
        -backend-config=retry_wait_min=5 
    - gitlab-terraform plan
    - gitlab-terraform validate
    - gitlab-terraform apply -auto-approve

tf_destroy:
  stage: destroy
  when: manual
  script:
    - source $(which gitlab-terraform)
    - >
       gitlab-terraform init \
        -backend-config=address=${TF_ADDRESS} \
        -backend-config=lock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
        -backend-config=unlock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock \
        -backend-config=username=${TF_USERNAME} \
        -backend-config=password=${TF_PASSWORD} \
        -backend-config=lock_method=POST \
        -backend-config=unlock_method=DELETE \
        -backend-config=retry_wait_min=5 
    - gitlab-terraform destroy -auto-approve
```